# Problem with transparency when using two world images

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, camera, transparency

In my setup I have two environment textures applied to my world. They are mixed using the factor of `Is Camera Ray`, like so:

[image]

The first environment node has a color grid, which is used for illumination. The second has a uv grid, which is shown to the camera.

So far, so good. If the scene is rendered with diffuse shaders this works perfectly. But when throwing transparency and reflections in the mix, things go south. Transparent objects will show the illuminating environment (color grid) rather than the one that is visible in the render (uv grid). Here's a quick render to illustrate the problem:

[image]

I can see why this is happening so probably I will need to look for an alternative route. Suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after. Something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/yLRde.png ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Basically what I'm after is only the illumination of the invisible environment (color grid). It shouldn't be visible anywhere else in the scene. Transparencies and reflections should show the uv grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange your nodes so that the color grid environment texture affects only the diffuse rays:

[image]

The sphere has a glass material and the big cube a glossy one. The small cube on top uses a diffuse shader.

Comment: Brilliant! that's exactly what I'm after. Many thanks!